# Mod Rewrite Rule for Dynamic URL - Is this possible?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've given myself a headache trying to figure out if this can be done. I have a forum that was recently migrated, leaving thousands of broken dynamic links.

A typical URL looks like this:

`http://domain.com/Forum_Name/b10001/25/`
('b10001' refers to the forum ID number and the last number refers to the page number.)

The new URL is formatted like this:

`http://domain.com/forums/Forum_Name.10001/`
(No page number. Also, notice the 'b' is no longer in front of the ID number.)

Is there a rewrite rule that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a rewriter, but following what I've read [here](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/), something like this should work:

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/b([0-9])+(/[0-9]+)?/?.*$    forums/$1.$2/   [NC,L]
```

`^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` says "begins with an alphanumeric string", then there's the `/b` constant, followed by `[0-9]+` (one or more digits), and then an optional / with one or more digit (the page number, `(/[0-9]+)?`), and lastly, it ends with an optional slash (`/?$`).

If the URL matches that pattern, then it's rewritten to `forums/$1\.$2/`. `\.` escapes the dot (it's a wildcard), `$1` is the first match of the pattern (that first alphanumeric string which is the forum name), and `$2` is the second match, namely, the number after the `b`.

Finally, `NC` means pattern is case-insensitive, and `L` is "last" - so you don't process any other rule. I think that is most up to you, just read the linked article and pick the flags you need :)

**Edit:** corrected pattern checking with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation, this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/b([0-9]+)/.*$ forums/$1/$2/
```

Make sure the contents of the [] parts match the format you're using for forum names and ids.

For parameters, you probably want `R=301` to force a permanent redirect.

Comment: With this syntax, would it matter if there is anything else at the end of the URL string, like an anchor hash?